# Trouble logging to AWS S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, async-await

I deployed a handler to AWS Lambda function using serverless framework with a custom designed logger which logs data to a unique AWS S3 object for every execution. When I tried to call this function's endpoint from a HTTP Client, it worked as expected for the first execution but is giving null as the output for subsequent executions. Only after a long gap, it is giving the expected output again. I think the issue is with the custom logger as I am not facing any issue if I remove the logger from the code and so I am attaching the code for the Logger class here

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var os = require("os");
var stream = require("stream");
AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY, secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, region: 'ap-south-1'});
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const BUCKET = process.env.S3_BUCKET;
var s3Stream = require('s3-upload-stream')(new AWS.S3())

class Logger{
    constructor(id){
        var date = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata'});
        var currentDate = new Date(date);
        var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
        var date = currentDate.getDate()
        this.file = currentDate.getFullYear().toString() + ((month.toString().length < 2) ? ('0' + month) : ('' + month)) + ((date.toString().length < 2) ? ('0' + date) : ('' + date)) + "-" + id;
        console.log("FILE: "+this.file)
        this.bucket = BUCKET;
        this.prefix = "logs/";
        this.stream = new stream.PassThrough();
        this.id = id;
        this.logContent = "";
    }

    streamLog(type,component,data){
        var date = new Date();
        var millis = date.getTime();
        this.stream.write(millis.toString() + " - " + this.id + " - [" + type + "]" + " - (" + component + "): " + data + os.EOL);
        this.logContent = this.logContent + millis.toString() + " - " + this.id + " - [" + type + "]" + " - (" + component + "): " + data + os.EOL;
    }

    uploadLogToS3(){
        this.stream.end();
        var upload = s3Stream.upload({
            "Bucket": BUCKET,
            "Key": this.prefix + this.file + ".log"
        });
        return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            console.log("ENTERED PROMISE");
            upload.on('error',function(error){
                console.log("ERROR STREAMING LOG TO S3: " + error);
                reject(0);
            })
            upload.on('uploaded',function(details){
                console.log("log successfully streamed to S3");
                resolve(1);
            })
            upload.on('part',function(details){
                console.log("UPLOADING LOG TO S3");
            })
            this.stream.pipe(upload);
        })
    }
    async finish(){
        try {
            console.log("ENTERED LOGGER FINISH");
            await this.uploadLogToS3();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("WRITING THE LOG STREAM TO CONSOLE");
            console.log(this.logContent);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the code for handler

```
module.exports.server = async function(event,context){
  console.log("ENTERED HANDLER");
  const MODULE_DESCRIPTION = "CONTROLLER GET BIRTHDAYS METHOD";
  var birthDays;
  var date = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata'});
  var currentDate = new Date(date);
  try {
    console.log("ENTERED TRY OF CONTROLLER GET BIRTHDAYS");
    [birthDays] = await Promise.all([API_LIB.getBirthDays(parseInt(currentDate.getDate()), parseInt(currentDate.getMonth() + 1),LOGGER)]);
    if (birthDays.length == 1){
      if (birthDays[0].hasOwnProperty("error")){
        LOGGER.streamLog("ERROR",MODULE_DESCRIPTION, birthDays[0].error || "ERROR with API call");
        await LOGGER.finish();
        return {status: 501,body: {error: 1,message: birthDays[0].error || "Internal server error"}}
      } else{
        LOGGER.streamLog("INFO",MODULE_DESCRIPTION,birthDays.toString());
        await LOGGER.finish();
        return {status: 200,body: birthDays}
      }
    } else{
      LOGGER.streamLog("INFO",MODULE_DESCRIPTION,birthDays.toString());
      await LOGGER.finish();
      return {status: 200,body: birthDays}
    }
  } catch (error) {
    LOGGER.streamLog("ERROR",MODULE_DESCRIPTION,error || "Internal server error");
    await LOGGER.finish();
    return {status: 501,body: {error: 1,message: error || "Internal server error"}}
  }
}
```

I am writing the logs to Logger using Logger.streamLog() in the entire code. Please help me figure out the issue with this Logger
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing your handler code, just a `Logger` class. You aren't showing how you actually use your `Logger` class. Without seeing the full Lambda function code I can only guess at the issue.

However, from your description it sounds like you are only initializing your `Logger` class once, so it correctly handles the first (cold) Lambda function execution, but on subsequent (warm) executions the logger isn't re-initialized so it isn't working properly.

Then, after some time, your function running container goes stale and is terminated, so the next time you call it you get another cold execution, which causes it to work again once.

I suggest reading up on how Lambda function [container reuse](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/) works.

If you need more help, please edit your original question to include the handler function and any code that uses the `Logger` class.

Comment: Sure Mark, I will edit the question and include the handler function

Comment: Thanks you so much Mark. i figured out the issue. I am initializing the logger in the initialization code and hence for the subsequent executions, Logger isn't initialized. I moved Logger initialized to the handler function and it is woking fine